# Disable placeholder CSS

Tags: css, placeholder

Within the woocommerce e-commerce.

I have an address field with the phrase "street name and house number" and I want to remove it.

Follow the images.

[image: not editable]

[image: editable]

I don't understand anything about any kind of programming, I just need a ready code, I'm grateful.

```
I can't take it off
```

Comment: I don't understand, I already looked at this topic.

I copied and pasted everything and nothing worked.

Comment: If you tried that and did not work, you need to post your code here to let other reproduce your problem and see that how it is not working. Please post your code as **text** not image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add css stylings to a placeholder you can achieve it with this

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  // your styles
}

::placeholder {
  // your styles
}
```

or if you want to remove your placeholder, remove the 'placeholder' attribute from the input tag

Comment: is this code working (below) how do i use it for google chrome desktop and mobile?

:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit browsers */
    color: transparent;
}
:not(:focus):-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: transparent;
}
:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: transparent;
}
:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: transparent;
}

Comment: I have tried your css in jsfiddle, the placeholder is shown only when i focus or click on the input, if this is flow you wanted then its working, you can check on jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/stormerthesecond/yc5mdkx9/

Comment: in google chrome no.